# Extending ETA Visa once in Australia as a US citizen?

Tags: visas, australia, us-citizens, eta

My US friend wants to spend 90 days in Australia though the remainder of her ETA expires after 56 days?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be possible. She'll need a new visa, if she doesn't want to leave and come back though.

According to the [Find a visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/Find-a-visa.aspx?Purpose=Visit%20Australia&Nationality=United%20States%20of%20America&ApplyFrom=United%20States%20of%20America&Age=All&Stay=Temporary&Length=Up%20to%203%20months&Family=All) page, she could apply, in Australia, for either a Visitor Visa (subclass 600) or a Work and Holiday Visa (subclass 462). They both indicate that she should be able to apply: from within Australia, online, for up to a year.

I would strongly suggest she read all of the notes on that page and figure out which would be best for her.